# Why does this MySQLi prepare statement fail to update the database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using MySQLi prepare statements in php.  The exact same code works on my local machine, but fails on the online server (it doesn't insert into the database table).  I'm a server noob, so I don't know if there's a setting I need to configure or not.  The `else` branch in the following code I got from another SO question, but it's not returning any errors.  I have the following at the top of my php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

edit to add: `$conn->prepare(....)` is returning `false`

```
$conn = new mysqli($SERVER, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tblTasks (taskID, blockNumber, transactionID, tasker, permlink, title, price, location, currency, tags, `status` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $taskID, $blockNumber, $transactionID, $tasker, $permlink, $taskTitle, $taskPrice, $location, $currency, $tags, $status);
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die("Insertion failed.");
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    $error = $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error;
    echo $error;
}
```

Comment: Since it was the call to `$conn->prepare` that failed, you need to echo `$conn->errno` and `$conn->error` as `$stmt` will be `false`, not an object (hence the error you are seeing)

Comment: @Nick, nup, still getting the same 'property of a non-object' error.

Comment: I notice the error is occurring on multiple lines (59 and 86) have you corrected all those lines of code?

Comment: Ah good catch.  I missed that.

Comment: @Nick it's not reporting any errors now.  I will update the question with the latest code

Comment: Try an explicit `COMMIT`

Comment: Where/how do I use that, @Quasimodo'sclone?  I tried using this notation - https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_commit.asp , but that didn't do anything.  Still no errors.

Comment: If the DBMS is not configured with `autocommit`, depending on the storage engine DML statements like `INSERT` are not actually written and a `ROLLBACK` is performed when the session is closed. You can commit changes at any point you want, e.g. after each DML or when multiple DML statements were done successfully. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html

Comment: That's SQL.  I need to know how to do it in PHP.  The code from w3schools did nothing.

Comment: Also use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to throw exceptions on errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments/22662582#22662582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help in the comments section I was able to implement successful error reporting, and found the error was a simple case of a capitalised table name when it shouldn't have been capitalised.  On my local windows environment capitalisation is ignored, whereas on the linux development environment capitalisation is strict!